# Excel - float number cannot be summed

Tags: excel, floating-point, sum

I have a bunch of values like 0.5, 1.0, 1.5 etc.

I want to write a SUM function for those cells but the value is 0.

If I use integers the summing works so there is something with the nbrs that is wrong. Maybe they are strings?
Because they end up to the left in the cell instead of the right like integers.

What do I need to do?

```
=SUM(H22:H26)
```

Comment: Try =ROUND(SUM(A1:A3),2)

Comment: How were those values entered into the cells?  They are definitely strings.  If they came from a web page, try converting them to numbers with something like =--trim(substitute(a1,char(160),""))

Answer (score 3):

Fell on the issue today: I exported data that I pasted into Excel. The formula `=SUM(B:B)` supposed to sum my decimals kept on returning 0...

It's stupid, but it made me lose 5 minutes: the decimal separator `.` had to be replaced by `,` or Excel wouldn't understand it as a decimal number.

Of course, it depends on Excel/system regional settings.

Answer (score 1):

In a new column, try multiplying the original column by 1; then sum the new column. Not sure, but that may fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the numbers to values first with

```
=value(H22), =value(H23), etc.
```

in `column G` and then do

```
=SUM(G22:G26)
```

Alternatively, you can just do

```
{=SUM(VALUE(H22:H26))}
```

Notice this is an array formula, so select it and hit `F2` and then `CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER`

Comment: But how can I loop over them and do it, I don't want to write value(cell) for each cell.

Comment: See my edit on making an array formula. That should take care of it for you.

Comment: should the {} be in there. I cannot get it to work either way

Comment: Sorry, I should have said, `CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER`.

Comment: Still the same problem #VALUE!

Comment: And you double-clicked in the cell with the formula and then hit `CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER` simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

Especially if the data came from a web page or HTML document, try the following

This formula must be **array-entered**:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(--TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A100,CHAR(160),"")),0))
```

---

To **array-enter** a formula, after entering
the formula into the cell or formula bar, hold down
**< ctrl >< shift >** while hitting **< enter >**.  If you did this
correctly, Excel will place braces **{...}** around the formula.

HTML frequently adds the NBSP character for spacing, and that must be removed specifically before Excel will see the value as a number.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do this in one cell, basically you should convert values and sum them

```
=VALUE(SUM(H22:H26))
```

Tried and verified!